# mediawiki API does not see the csrf token

Tags: post, csrf, mediawiki, mediawiki-api, csrf-token

When running my own mediawiki on localhost I run into a problem with the api endpoint for editing a page. The api works fine otherwise. For instance when querying tokens I get the following output:

```sh
$ curl "http://localhost/api.php?action=query&meta=tokens&type=createaccount|csrf|login&format=json"

{"batchcomplete":"","query":{"tokens":{"createaccounttoken":"1e5c2ce3f9e12fdab05a0e6e6352da3162644214+\\","csrftoken":"+\\","logintoken":"35ee2e6ccbbd654bcfada9cddab07f7662634214+\\"}}}
```

Interestingly the `csrftoken` has the strange value '+\\', which also seems to be appended to the logintoken.

When posting an edit action (for an existing page called Alice) with this token I get the reponse that the token is missing from the post body. But it's not missing, or is it?

```sh
$ curl -X POST "http://localhost/api.php?action=edit&title=Alice&summary=test&text=article&baserevid=0&token=+\\&format=json"

{"error":{"code":"mustpostparams","info":"The following parameter was found in the query string, but must be in the POST body: token.","*":"See http://localhost/api.php for API usage. Subscribe to the mediawiki-api-announce mailing list at &lt;https://lists.wikimedia.org/postorius/lists/mediawiki-api-announce.lists.wikimedia.org/&gt; for notice of API deprecations and breaking changes."}}
```

Then I followed [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44244272/mediawiki-invalid-login-token) and added the [`cookie-jar` option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399087/curl-to-access-a-page-that-requires-a-login-from-a-different-page) to make the `curl` request from the same session, but it gave the same error response. Any ideas?

By the way I used the `docker.io/bitnami/mediawiki:1` docker image together with a `mariadb` to set up my mediawiki.

Comment: The value token is actually `+\` (which gets encoded into JSON as (`"+\\"`), although `"+\\"` in bash is also `+\" so that works out. Putting a literal `+` sign into the URL (as opposed to percent-encoding) probably wouldn't, though. But as AXO points out, you can't put it into the URL anyway.

Comment: (FWIW the value was chosen to detect HTTP and JSON encoding problems, so that faulty clients get a token error rather than mess up the text of the article.)

Comment: Thanks @Tgr, Thanks for the information. However having tried all sorts of variations: ` +\`,  +\", +` etc etc none of them worked. i also passed the data via the --data option of curl and I tried it with python requests import requests: 
`data = {'action':'edit',
        'title':'Alice',
        'summary':'test summary',
        'text':'articla text',
        'baserevid': 0,
        'token': '+\`',
        'format': 'json'}
req = requests.post(
    url="http://localhost/api.php",
    data=data)`

Comment: yes it worked. Thanks. Actually passing 'token': '+\\' as a key-value pair in the data dictionary worked.

Comment: If you want to make this into an answer, please go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

> `The following parameter was found in the query string, but must be in the POST body`

I'm not very familiar with `curl` but it seems that you are sending a post request with the params in the query part. Try sending them in the post body as the error suggests:

```
curl --data "action=edit&title=Alice&summary=test&text=article&baserevid=0&token=+\\&format=json" http://localhost/api.php
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I followed your advice partly to not use curl and to pass the data separately. It seems that there is a formatting issue with the +\\" in bash, so after using python it seemed to work. @Tgr gave the other decisive hint.